# Making Tracy bounce from edge to edge

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make Tracy do a DVD screensaver sort of thing with random angles to fill the screen with randomly-colored lines, but I'm unsure of how to make her not keep going off the screen.

Here's my current code for it:

```
def background():
    speed(1)
    pensize(5)
    line_count = 0
    while line_count < 101:
        color(random.choice(color_list))
        left(random.choice(angle_list))
        pendown()
        while (xcor() > -200) or (xcor() < 200) or (ycor() > -200) or (ycor() < 200):
            forward(1)
        line_count+=1
```

Every time I run it, she picks a random color and angle as intended, but never stops at the edge and floats off into the void

Comment: Could it be that you mean "and" instead of "or" in your while loop? All of these should be true, not just one, right?

Comment: Tried changing "or" to "and" and it draws the first line, but then it just gets stuck on the edge and doesn't make any more lines

Comment: To "bounce", Tracy would have to change direction, but in your code, Tracy only ever goes "forward".

Answer (score 0):

Trying to maintain the spirit of your "Tracy", how about something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

COLOR_LIST = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'cyan']

angle_list = [15 * n for n in range(24)]

def background():
    turtle.color(choice(COLOR_LIST))
    turtle.left(choice(angle_list))

    while -200 < turtle.xcor() < 200 and -200 < turtle.ycor() < 200:
        turtle.forward(1)

    turtle.backward(1)
    screen.ontimer(background)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.pensize(5)

background()

screen.mainloop()
```

> Tried changing "or" to "and" and it draws the first line, but then it
> just gets stuck on the edge

That's because you exit your loop when the turtle is stuck, so it remains so.  By calling `backward(1)`, we undo the last move that got us into trouble.

Comment: Works great (I'm using CodeHS so I don't think the "turtle." is necessary, not entirely sure though). Where would I put a while/for loop to make it repeat?

Comment: @SamuelMaurer, it already repeats.

Comment: when I copy it and run it, it only makes one line and then the code stops running

Comment: @SamuelMaurer, under what environment are you running Python?  I.e. any IDE like PyCharm involved?  Windows or Unix?

Comment: I mentioned it in a previous comment, but I'm using CodeHS

Comment: @SamuelMaurer, I went onto CodeHS (not as a registered user), pasted my code in and it runs fine.  The output window is not centered in their output screen, but it's busily drawing multiple lines.